# GmailMessage.foward() cc's self

Tags: google-apps-script

I noticed that `GmailApp.sendEmail()` and `GmailMessage.forward()` cc's the account that it is sent from. When I send or forward a message with Apps Script I always get a copy from "me" (even if I supply the 'name' option something else). Is there a way to suppress this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The Gmailapp.sendmail function won't cc you but it would save a copy of the sent message in your sent items folder. An alternative would be mailapp.sendmail since it won't save a copy.

Comment: If I do `MailApp.sendMail('someaddr@domain.org', 'subject', 'body')` I immediately see a new mail in my inbox from "me" even though my address is nowhere to be found in the To: field. I even checked the header to confirm this. The same is true about `GmailApp.sendMail()`, and `GmailMessage.forward()`